# Как выйти из vim?

Tags: vim

Не знаю как закрыть этот редактор. уже все кнопки понажимал. помоги?

гуглил. ничего не помогло. только один совет - вытащить батарейку на ноуте и вставить. неужели так постоянно надо делать?

Comment: а справку вы не пробовали читать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11828573/1216425

Comment: Esc, потом :q!  - это чтобы не сохранять что внесли

Comment: Типа юморист тут завелся? С бородатыми шутками про vim

Comment: да ладно вам, на enso такой же вопрос очень популярен. Почти 2 миллиона просмотров

Comment: Попробуйте vimtutor запустить, там написано что надо нажимать.

Comment: Не забудьте после выхода из Vi войти в Emacs. Он намного лучше!